# Calling database set method inside construct

Tags: php, oop

I am new to OOP so this is probably a simple solution. I am trying to clean up my code a little bit so that I don't have to do so much when I create an object. My code is below:

```
include "Database.php";

Class Database {
    protected $conn;

    public function setDb($conn){
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
}

Class Images extends Database{
    protected $conn;
    protected $stmt;

    function __construct(){

    }

    public function RetrieveImages(){
        $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `pictures`');
        $this->stmt->execute();
        $boom = $this->stmt->fetchAll();
        return $boom;
    }
}

$db = new Images();
$db->setDb($conn);
$test = $db->RetrieveImages();
var_dump($test);
```

Database.php:

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', 'blah','boom!');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

This code is working fine but I would like to automate the `$db->setDb($conn);` part. Is there a way I can call this automatically so I can initiate the object like

```
$db = new Images();
$db->RetrieveImages();
```

I have tried adding

```
$db = new Database();
$db->setDb($conn);
```

to the constructor method inside the Images class but I get an error

> Call to a member function `prepare()` on non object

I tried several different ways to get this working but I am not able to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can call this automatically so I can initiate the object

That's not a very desirable property of any code; it prevents testability of your code; ignoring the unfortunate naming of your classes I would set it up like this:

```
class Database 
{
    protected $conn;

    public function __construct($conn)
    {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
}
```

Then your `Images` class becomes:

```
class Images extends Database
{
    public function RetrieveImages()
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `pictures`');
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

To call the whole thing:

```
// $conn was created in "Database.php"
$images = new Images($conn);
print_r($images->RetrieveImages());
```

Comment: You said above that its not a desirable property of any code, I am new and learning a lot still so I want to learn the right way. The above code that you posted and said this is how you would set it up, is this the right way that is desirable or the way that accomplishes what I asked to be done?

Comment: @Yamaha32088 It merely serves to show you that a dependency such as a database connection should be "injected" into your objects instead of created inside of it. This way you can "rewire" your objects more easily.

Comment: Maybe I can't but I just want to edit `$tmt` to `$stmt`...Sorry, I'm a newbie here...

Answer (score 0):

Your `Database` class has no database anythings.

It does not do anything.

---

You need to have a MySQLi or PDO object somewhere to do databsse calls.

Comment: It does I include a script that has all of that it has an object $conn that is passed

Comment: @Yamaha32088 where is `$conn` defined?

Comment: After you assign it, what is it's value when you do a `var_dump` on `$conn`?